# LabView - how to change scales on Waveform graph without changing the display?

Tags: charts, labview

I want to change Y and X axis of the Waveform graph for Autocorellation function.
This is how the Graph looks now:

[image: waveform graph image]

And I would like the scale for X to be from -1 to 1 and Y from -0.1 to 1, however when I changed the scale manually in properties, the display changed completly and most of the chart was unseen, as shown on the image below:

[image: waveform graph image 2]

I guess the problem is there because of indexig or that the X is scaled using Sampling info i.e. it is displaying sample numbers.

How can I rescale the X axis so it will show time instead of number of sample?

This is how the WaveformGraph 5 is being created:

As I have said I have tried changing the properties of X and Y axis manually, but it just "cut out" the bigger part of the Chart.

Answer (score 0):

If you wire an actual waveform data type into the Waveform Graph then its horizontal axis should display the waveform time, not the number of data points. Your question is missing the block diagram code so I can't see how you are supplying the data to the graph.

If you edit the X and Y axis scales, you're not just changing the text; you're changing what you are telling the graph to display. This is the intended behaviour.

However if you want the displayed scale to be different from the actual scale on which the data is plotted, you can bring up the Properties window for the graph indicator, select the **Scales** pane and edit the **Offset** and **Multiplier** values. Here I have placed two Waveform Graphs with the same input data, but edited the scales for the second one:

[image: block diagram (VI Snippet)]

[image: front panel with waveform graphs]